# C# mondodb retrieve data from collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to get the data from my collection, I found the search document but I have some trouble to get the value from the response. I need from the UserAdress the city.

My document in the database looks like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(337),
    "userId" : "User_337",
    "active" : false,
    "UserAdress" : {
        "street" : "testweg",
        "plz" : "12345",
        "countryCode" : "DE",
        "city" : "berlin"
    }
}
```

The code looks like:

```html
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var db = client.GetDatabase("EV");
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("endUser");
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filt = builder.Eq("_id", 337);
var list = collection.Find(filt).ToList();
```

Thanks, Donald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result you'll get a list of `BsonDocuments`. You can use `.First()` since `_id` is unique and then access nested property using square brackets `[]` - like in .NET dictionaries:

```
var filt = builder.Eq("_id", 337);
var doc = collection.Find(filt).First();
var city = doc["UserAdress"]["city"].AsString;
```